# Spring MVC and JSR-303 hibernate conditional validation

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I've a form I want to validate. It contains 2 Address variables. address1 has always to be validated, address2 has to be validated based on some conditions

```
public class MyForm {
    String name;
    @Valid Address address1;
    Address address2;
 }

public class Address {
    @NotEmpty   
    private String street;
}
```

my controller automatically validates and binds my form obj

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ModelAndView edit(
        @ModelAttribute("form")
        @Valid
        MyForm form,
        BindingResult bindingResult,
        ...)

        if(someCondition) {
            VALIDATE form.address2 USING JSR 303
```

the problem is that if I use the LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator i can't reuse the BinidingResult object provided by Spring. The bind won't work as the target object of 'result' is 'MyForm' and not 'Address'

```
validate(form.getAddress2(), bindingResult)   //won't work
```

I'm wondering what's the standard/clean approach to do conditional validation.

I was thinking in programmatically create a new BindingResult in my controller.

```
final BindingResult bindingResultAddress2 = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(address2, "form");
validate(form.getAddress2(), bindingResultAddress2);
```

but then the List of errors I obtain from bindingResultAddress2 can't be added to the general 'bindingResult' as the field names are not correct ('street' instead of 'address2.street') and the binding won't work.

Some dirty approach would be to extend BeanPropertyBindingResult to accept some string to append to the fields name.. do you have a better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard approach for validating hierarchical structures is to use `pushNestedPath()`/`popNestedPath()`, though I'm not sure how it plays with JSR-303:

```
bindingResult.pushNestedPath("address2");
validate(form.getAddress2(), bindingResult);
bindingResult.popNestedPath();
```

Comment: Thanks axtavt, it works. I'm wondering if this is the best approach to make it, why there's no groups attribute in @Valid and if JSR-303 groups concept is the only way to achieve conditional validation

Comment: There is a feature request for groups in `@Valid`: https://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-6373

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried myself, but I think the correct approach is using [validator groups](http://people.redhat.com/~ebernard/validation/#validationapi-validatorapi-groups).

Comment: Unfortunately @Valid has no groups

Comment: It is unfortunate - see my comment above.  I think it'd be a great addition to the spec and that this level of practicality should be favored over idealism.

Comment: Or to appease the idealists, we should stop calling this a 'Bean Validation Framework' and start calling it a 'Java Validation Framework' and add support for method arguments and return values in addition to object graphs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's see [@javax.validation.Valid](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/Valid.html) API

> **Mark an association as cascaded**. The associated object will be validated by cascade.

When Spring framework uses @Valid **as a marker** to validate its command objects, it corrupts its purpose. Spring should instead create your own specific annotation which specifies the groups which should be validated.

Unfortunately, you should use Spring native Validator API if you need to validate some groups

```
public void doSomething(Command command, Errors errors) {
    new BeanValidationValidator(SomeUserCase.class, OtherUserCase.class)
        .validate(command, errors);

    if(errors.hasErrors()) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

BeanValidationValidator can be implemented as

```
public class BeanValidationValidator implements Validator {

    javax.validation.Validator validator = ValidatorUtil.getValidator();

    private Class [] groups;

    public BeanValidationValidator(Class... groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    public void validate(Object command, Errors errors) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolationSet = validator.validate(command, groups);

        for(ConstraintViolation<Object> constraintViolation: constraintViolationSet) {
            errors.rejectValue(constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString(), null, constraintViolation.getMessage()); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I respectfully disagree that adding groups to the @Valid annotation would be a corruption of its purpose.  I see it as an enhancement.

@Valid says "this object should be validated".  Adding groups would effectively mean "this object should be validated in this way".  There is no reason why that same statement couldn't apply to cascaded associations for object graphs as well as method arguments.

Also, specifications should evolve with obvious valuable additions; Adding groups to @Valid would allow many frameworks to eliminate repeated code.  Specs should favor practicality over idealism.